# Wordpress and woocommerce Food Delivery Site

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to create a food delivery site, where users can search restaurants closest to there location and place order.
Similar to [www.easyappetite.com](http://www.easyappetite.com) & [www.just-eat.ca](http://www.just-eat.ca)

The simple logic is for users to enter there location then every registered restaurant in that location come up with there menu and user can make order.

How can i achieve this using wordpress and woocommerce? what plugins will i need and generally the system logic.

I have spent night crawling Google but with no luck

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

I have used this one on bunch of sites. You can add the locations of all the restaurants and then drop it any where. It says dealer locator, but it can be customised for anything.

http://www.viadat.com/store-locator/